# Sharing of dedicated IP across multiple BUs in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, sender-authentication-package

**Scenario:**

- Marketing Cloud instance with multiple business units
- Different primary sendout domains used in every BU
- Sendout volume to low in one business unit to keep IP warmed up

It is desired to have a dedicated IP that that is shared with other BUs in the same Marketing Cloud instance, so the IP can be kept warmed up and the responsibility for sender reputation remains within the instance/corporation. Due to low sendout volume per BU a dedicated IP per BU/SAP (sender authentication package) isn't possible and sharing an IP with other Marketing Cloud customers/instances isn't desired either.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have a dedicated IP that is shared across multiple business units, which are each using different sendout domains and SAPs (sender authentication packages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible to use same IP with multiple SAPs. The only requirement is, they are all on the same stack (e.g. s7.exacttarget.com).

When you request additional SAPs [here](https://senderauth.marketingcloud.com/), you need to provide information in comments, that you wish to use an existing IP address, and which one you want to use.